# Calculate mean between 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, mean

I have a matrix (100x50, it has random numbers) stored as x(:,:,1) and x(:,:,2). I want to calculate the average corresponding to the row and column of these matrixes but no luck so far. I tried to use the mean function but it gives me only one value. Any tips for an algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get for each matrix like the following:

```
  mean(x(:,:,1),1) //avg in columns of x(:,:,1)
  mean(x(:,:,1),2) //avg in row of x(:,:,1)
```

Also you can get the mean of x in different dimension using the following code:

```
 mean(x,3); // size 100x50, avg of element of the two matrices
 mean(x,2); // size 100 x 1 x 2, avg of rows of the two matrices
 mean(x,1); // size 1 x 50 x 2, avg of columns of the two matrices
```

Comment: You see how you wrote 'mean(x(:,:,1),1) //avg in columns of x(:,:,1)', do you mean column or columns?